# Unable to access class variables

Tags: swift

I have the following swift class

```
import Foundation

class Tips
{
    //Variables
    var totalBill: Float
    var tipPercent: Int
    var splitBy: Int

    init(billAmount: Float, tipPercentage: Int, splitByPeople: Int)
    {
        totalBill = billAmount
        tipPercent = tipPercentage
        splitBy = splitByPeople
    }

    class func calculateTip() -> Float
    {
        var grandTotal = totalBill + ((totalBill * tipPercent)/100)
        return grandTotal/splitBy
    }

}
```

In the `calculateTip()` function, I am seeing an error called `Instance member "totalBill" cannot be used on type "Tips"`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should remove **class** keyword before func calculateTip() :

```
class func calculateTip() -> Float
```

become

```
func calculateTip() -> Float
```

Using **class** keyword make your function static, and so you cannot access to class member because, the class is not instanciated

I recommend to use Float everywhere:

```
class Tips
{
    //Variables
    var totalBill: Float
    var tipPercent: Float
    var splitBy: Float

    init(billAmount: Float, tipPercentage: Int, splitByPeople: Int)
    {
        totalBill = billAmount
        tipPercent = Float(tipPercentage) // <--convert
        splitBy = Float(splitByPeople) // <--convert
    }

    class func calculateTip() -> Float
    {
        var grandTotal = totalBill + ((totalBill * tipPercent)/100)
        return grandTotal/splitBy
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Also, I am getting an error called "Binary operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Int', when computing grandTotal in the above function. Any ideas, if I need some kind of type conversion?

Comment: you need to use the same type, by converting your Int to Float. with: Float(variableName)

Comment: ah.. I see.. That makes sense.. Thank you :)

Comment: Alternatively, he could instead declare his variables as `static`, depending on whether it makes sense to call the method on a specific instance or not.